# SonarQube startup java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PanwHooks

Tags: java, sonarqube

When I start sonarqube 8.9 on CentOS 8 server. startup failing with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PanwHooks` Exception message.

tried different startup method getting the same exception. Any tips to fix this issue?

```
jvm 1    | WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to complete.
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
jvm 1    | 2021.07.16 21:45:47 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-8.9.0.43852/temp
jvm 1    | 2021.07.16 21:45:47 DEBUG app[][o.s.a.NodeLifecycle] WrapperSimpleAppMain tryToMoveTo from INIT to STARTING => true
jvm 1    | 2021.07.16 21:45:47 DEBUG app[][o.s.a.p.ManagedProcessLifecycle] WrapperSimpleAppMain tryToMoveTo es from INIT to STARTING => true
jvm 1    | 2021.07.16 21:45:47 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch cluster enabled. Connect to hosts [192.168.81.88,192.168.81.107,192.168.81.108]
jvm 1    | 2021.07.16 21:45:47 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 192.168.81.108:9001, TCP: 192.168.81.108:9002]
jvm 1    | 2021.07.16 21:45:47 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-8.9.0.43852/elasticsearch]:
/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-8.9.0.43852/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PanwHooks
jvm 1    | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PanwHooks
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.ProcessLauncherImpl$JavaLangProcessBuilder.start(ProcessLauncherImpl.java:379)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.ProcessLauncherImpl.launchExternal(ProcessLauncherImpl.java:128)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.ProcessLauncherImpl.launch(ProcessLauncherImpl.java:97)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.SchedulerImpl.lambda$tryToStartProcess$2(SchedulerImpl.java:196)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler.start(ManagedProcessHandler.java:73)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.SchedulerImpl.tryToStartProcess(SchedulerImpl.java:194)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.SchedulerImpl.tryToStartEs(SchedulerImpl.java:146)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.SchedulerImpl.tryToStartAll(SchedulerImpl.java:138)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.SchedulerImpl.schedule(SchedulerImpl.java:112)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.App.start(App.java:68)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.App.main(App.java:97)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) end.  Main Completed=true, exitCode=1
jvm 1    | WrapperListener.start runner thread stopped.
jvm 1    | returned from WrapperListener.start()
jvm 1    | WrapperListener.start() returned an exit code of 1.
```

Thanks

Comment: have you checked that post https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-service-keeps-restarting-8-2-ubuntu18/33712/3?

Comment: yes, It didn't help me.

Comment: Hi @sfgroups. Please, how do you start sonarqube? How did you installed the service?

Comment: @jccampanero  as a functional account, starting like this `/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-8.9.0.43852/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh console`

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems the problem is related to elasticsearch, maybe there is something wrong with it, although I honestly don't know what. Probably it is unrelated, but be aware that the [docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.9/setup/environment-variables/) indicate some restrictions about elasticsearch virtual memory, may be it can be related, but as I told you, I do not know, sorry.

Comment: Hi @sfgroups, I'm not able to reproduce the issue with an up to date CentOS 8.4.2105 and the system's jdk 11 (`openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS`). Are you using a different jdk distribution (Oracle's or adoptopenjdk maybe) ?. Also, did you change sonarqube's default configuration? (particularly, did you add a java agent to the jvm startup settings : `-javaagent:xxxx`)

Comment: Can you please add `wrapper.debug=true` to the end of `conf/wrapper.conf`, launch `sonar.sh console` and share the output.

Comment: @MohamedAMAZIRH  I was using openjdk `.11.0.11` before, I have upgraded to opendk `11.0.12`. now  SonarQube is starting.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue with the version 11.0.11 but I couldn't. Great that it's working now for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After upgrading openjdk to `11.0.12` SonarQube is starting.

```
# java -version
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.12+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.12+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 1):

A search on the SonarQube community revealed [this post](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-service-keeps-restarting-8-2-ubuntu18/33712/2).  They seemed to indicate if you are running systemd, you do not need the wrapper and pointed people to the guide located [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/operate-server/#header-3). They posted their resolved systemd configuration file, which you haven't, so it may not be the same issue, but you are failing with the same 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PanwHooks` issue, both of you were on platforms that use systemd, and their solution involved modifying the systemd configuration to remove the Listener.

Comment: I am not using the systemd, using sonar.sh script to start.